# Как в Objective-J отправить запрос на получение RSS ленты?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Недавно начал знакомится с web фреймверком [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/). Подскажите пожалуйста как отправить запрос на получение RSS ленты?

Пробовал делать вот таким способом:

```
var request = [CPURLRequest requestWithURL:"http://www.domain.ru/rss.xml"];
var connection = [CPURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
...

- (void)connection:(CPURLConnection)aConnection didReceiveData:(CPString)data
{
CPLog.debug(data);    
}
```

Но CPLog.debug(data); выводить в FireBug пустую строку.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите здесь: [cappuccino-rss-reader-tutorial](https://github.com/gregbell/cappuccino-rss-reader-tutorial).

```
var request = [CPURLRequest requestWithURL:"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=" + encodeURIComponent([aFeed url])];
[request setValue:@"http://gregbell.ca" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Referer"];

[CPJSONPConnection sendRequest:request callback:"callback" delegate:self];
```